# AttributeError in Kivy: GridLayout object has no attribute _trigger_layout

Tags: python, widget, textures, kivy, attributeerror

I'm trying to write a program in python that takes parts of an image and renders them in kivy using a GridLayout.

Using an XML file with my map data, I'm reading each tile from their Global ID (or "GID", see [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/parsing-and-rendering-tiled-tmx-format-maps-in-your-own-game-engine--gamedev-3104) for an explanation of how it works and the process my program's using), converting the source tileset image into a texture, and taking a region of that texture with the .get_region() method. I then create an Image widget with that part of the texture to go in the GridLayout. But I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test_parse_xml.py", line 92, in 
>       Ground = Layer(root[1].attrib['name'], int(root[1].attrib['width']),  int(root[1].attrib['height']))
>     File "test_parse_xml.py", line 85, in **init**
>       self.add_widget(Image(current_texture)) #returns an error. What am I  doing wrong?
>   File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/kivy/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 85, in add_widget
>       size=self._trigger_layout,
>   AttributeError: 'Layer' object has no attribute '_trigger_layout'

Any ideas on how I can fix this? The point of interest is the line that says

```
self.add_widget(Image(current_texture))
```

Here's my complete program.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window

tree = ET.parse('test_tileset.tmx')
root = tree.getroot()


#import general elements from <map> tag
mapWidth = int(root.attrib['width'])
mapHeight = int(root.attrib['height'])
tileWidth = int(root.attrib['tilewidth'])
tileHeight = int(root.attrib['tileheight'])


class TileSet(object):
    """Stores data about tilesets to be accessed by tiles from that tileset"""

    def __init__(self, imagePath, imageWidth, imageHeight,    #creating instance attributes of the class,
                 tilesetFirstGid, tilesetTileWidth, tilesetTileHeight): #change values with each instance
        self.imagePath = imagePath
        self.imageWidth = imageWidth
        self.imageHeight = imageHeight
        self.tilesetFirstGid = tilesetFirstGid
        self.tilesetTileWidth = tilesetTileWidth
        self.tilesetTileHeight = tilesetTileHeight
        self.tilesetLastGid = (imageHeight//tilesetTileHeight)*(imageWidth//tilesetTileWidth)


#make a list of all the tilesets
tilesetList = []

#import data for each tileset from each <tileset> tag
Test = TileSet(root[0][0].attrib['source'], int(root[0][0].attrib['width']),
               int(root[0][0].attrib['height']), int(root[0].attrib['firstgid']),
               int(root[0].attrib['tilewidth']), int(root[0].attrib['tileheight'])
               )
tilesetList.append(Test)



def get_tileset(gid):
    """takes an integer, the gid. Returns an instance of the tileset that has that gid"""

    for i in tilesetList:
        if gid <= i.tilesetLastGid:
            return i



class Layer(GridLayout):
    """creates a grid of tiles based on information from a layer."""

    def __init__(self, name, width, height, **kwargs):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        #set the number of columns of the gridlayout
        self.cols = width

        #get the layer for ease of iteration below
        #using XPath to find all 'data' nodes that are children of nodes
        #with the name of the instance of the class
        self.layer = root.find(".//*[@name='"+self.name+"']/data")


        prevgid = 1
        current_texture = Image(Test.imagePath).texture
        current_texture = current_texture.get_region(0, 0, 32, 32)
        for gid in self.layer:
            gid = int(gid.attrib['gid'])
            if gid > 0:
                if gid != prevgid:
                    ts = get_tileset(gid)
                    current_texture = Image(ts.imagePath).texture
                    #getting a region of the texture based off the Global ID (GID)
                    current_texture = current_texture.get_region((ts.imageWidth//ts.tilesetTileWidth-1)*ts.tilesetTileWidth,
                                                                     (ts.imageHeight//ts.tilesetTileHeight-1)*ts.tilesetTileHeight,
                                                                     ts.tilesetTileWidth, ts.tilesetTileHeight)
                    prevgid = gid

                self.add_widget(Image(current_texture)) #returns an error. What am I doing wrong? 
                                                        #Is there a better way to add the texture to the GridLayout?
            else:
                self.add_widget() #something will go here once I figure out my main problem



Ground = Layer(root[1].attrib['name'], int(root[1].attrib['width']), int(root[1].attrib['height']))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Ground().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call your super constructor in your `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self, name, width, height, **kwargs):
    GridLayout.__init__(self, cols=2, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=40, spacing=[0, 1],**kwargs)
    self.name = str(name)
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
```

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the error, but I still couldn't get the Image widget to work:
File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 438, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind (kivy/_event.c:6026)
 KeyError: 'size_hint')

So I used self.canvas.add(Rectangle(texture=current_texture)) and it drew a white box in the bottom left corner of the screen... I need to figure out how to get that the texture region to display.

Comment: i usually use `kivy.uix.image.Image` when i need to put an image on the screen (but im not making games either)